# Changing Wide Data back to Long Format - VBA. How to Select Sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been looking for a wide to long format code for a while now and found on here something very useful. I have took that and made some modifications to it to apply to my data... Works perfectly.

My question though is, where do I add in Sheet selection? I.e. I want to be able to run the macro from a button on a different page. At the moment the code only works if executed from the orignal source sheet.

```
Sub Wide_To_Long()

Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, Dta, col As Integer
Dim c As Integer, LastDt As Integer, LastVis As Integer
 LastDt = Cells("1", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set Rng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
ReDim Ray(1 To Rng.Count * LastDt, 1 To LastDt)
For Each Dn In Rng
  LastVis = Cells(Dn.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
      For col = 8 To LastVis
        c = c + 1
            For Dta = 0 To 8
                Select Case Dta
                    Case Is = 7
                    Ray(c, Dta + 1) = Cells(1, col)
                    Case Is = 8
                    Ray(c, Dta + 1) = Dn.Offset(, col - 1)
                    Case Else
                    Ray(c, Dta + 1) = Dn.Offset(, Dta)
                End Select
            Next Dta
    Next col

Next Dn
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(c, LastDt).Value = Ray

End Sub
```

Comment: you can set your sheet at the beginning - let's say set ws = sheets("Sheet1") - then put ws before .range, i.e., ws.range("A2")

Comment: Okay, so if I set ws=sheet "x" then were would I add ws in? Would it be something like this? : Set Rng = ws.Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a better was to do it (if from Lowpar know where to make change), but I found that inserting before the first dim a sheets("").Select to the sheet the data rang is on worked just fine.